# IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncQueryProvider when convert Enumerable to IQueryable

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I use [ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging) Nuget package for paging data but when I want to use `CreateAsync` method it return this exception :

> The provider for the source 'IQueryable' doesn't implement'IAsyncQueryProvider'.
>
> Only providers that implement'IAsyncQueryProvider' can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.

[image]

This a simple Code that can create exception

**Note :** I use `unit of work` pattern to call data

1. This is my Entity

```
public class Entity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    
    public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

2. This is my view Model

```
public class ViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

3. This my `Context` class

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext() : base() { }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Connection-String");
    }

    public DbSet<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
}
```

4. This my `Repository` example

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public Repository(DataContext context) => dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();

    public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> ReadAllAsync() => await dbSet.ToListAsync();
}

public interface IRepository<TEntity>
{
    Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> ReadAllAsync();
}
```

5. This is `UnitOfWork` Example

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly DataContext context;

    public UnitOfWork() => context = new();

    public IRepository<TEntity> RepositoryBase<TEntity>() where TEntity :  class
    {    
        return new Repository<TEntity>(context);
    }
}

public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    IRepository<TEntity> RepositoryBase<TEntity>() where TEntity :  class;
}
```

6. In `Program` file add its service

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
```

7. Now add it to controller and use it in action like this

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public HomeController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var model = (await _unitOfWork.RepositoryBase<Entity>().ReadAllAsync())
                    .Select(i => new ViewModel() 
                                 { 
                                     Id = i.Id, 
                                     Name = i.Name, 
                                     LastName = i.LastName 
                                 }).AsQueryable();

        var PagingModel = await PagingList.CreateAsync(model, 10, 10, "Name", "Name"); //! Error Line

        PagingModel.RouteValue = new RouteValueDictionary
        {
            {"row", 10 }
        };

        return View(PagingModel);
    }
}
```

**Note :** These code just a sample from main project.

Comment: Return `IQueryable` from repository. You will NEVER need to load WHOLE table into memory (or better throw away this anti-pattern). Your exception is clear: you cannot apply async functions to `IQueryable` made from `IEnumerable`. `IQueryable` should start from `DbSet`.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv It's work correctly you can answer it to be accepted and other user better see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exception is clear: you cannot apply async functions to `IQueryable` made from `IEnumerable`. `IQueryable` should start from `DbSet`

Your repository implementation has big drawback it has method `ReadAllAsync()` which loads whole table into the memory.

Change realization to return `IQueryable`:

```cs
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public Repository(DataContext context) => dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();

    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery() => dbSet;
}

public interface IRepository<TEntity>
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery();
}
```

Then just use in proper way:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var model = _unitOfWork.RepositoryBase<Entity>().GetQuery()
                .Select(i => new ViewModel() 
                { 
                    Id = i.Id, 
                    Name = i.Name, 
                    LastName = i.LastName 
                });

    var PagingModel = await PagingList.CreateAsync(model, 10, 10, "Name", "Name"); //! Error Line

    PagingModel.RouteValue = new RouteValueDictionary
    {
        {"row", 10 }
    };

    return View(PagingModel);
}
```

BUT, if you start learning EF Core, consider do not use Generic Repository pattern. It is anti-pattern for EF Core, `DbSet` is already repository, `DbContext` is already multi-repository UnitOfWork. You just add another not needed abstraction.